# Python BeautifulSoup does not see dropdown list option values

Tags: python

I want to get the dropdown list option values with Python, but Beatifulsoup does not seem to find any objects in the webpage.

From a webpage I exttract a script object:

```html
<script id="template_white-popup" type="text/template">
    <div class="geo-info">
        <p class="a-center">
            Select a shop near you        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row fields first localization-white-popup">
        <div class="col-xs-12 a-center"></div>
    </div>
    {{#if localization}}
    <div class="row fields localization-content">
        <button id="btn-setGeolocalisationWhitePopup" type="button" class="button btn-blue">
            <span>Locate me</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if marketsFounded}}
    <div class="geo-info">
        <div class="row fields">
            <div class="a-center info-markets">
                Select a shop in your area:
            </div>
            {{#each markets}}
                <button class="shop-address" data-market-id="{{this.id}}" data-store-id="{{this.id_market_castorama}}">
                    {{this.name}}
                </button>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    <div class="geo-info a-center"></div>
    <div class="row fields">
      <div class="a-center info-markets">Find a shop on a list below:</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row fields last">
        <div class="choose-single-market-with-list">
            <select name="choose-market" id="geolocation-popup-select-market" style="display: none;">
                <option selected>Select Shop</option>
    <option value="59" data-store-view="8016" >  Shopnr1   </option>
    <option value="42" data-store-view="8018" > Shopnr2     </option>
    <option value="27" data-store-view="8013" >  Shopnr3 </option>
   </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Running find on this element does not return anything, no div, no option..

```py
soup.find('div', {'class':'geo-info'})
soup.find("select",{'name':'choose-market'}).findAll("option")
```

I would like to get a list of shops with their corresponding value from the list:

```
Shopnr1 59 8016
Shopnr2 42 8018
Shopnr3 27 8013
```

There is probably something in this html code that makes Beautifulsoup blind, but I do not know how to get around it.

Comment: can you post the website?

Comment: I edit a bit the above html code to shorten the list of options, but the rest is the same. website: https://www.castorama.pl/produkty/wykonczenie/drewno-i-drewnopodobne/podlogi-drewniane.html

Comment: I run this code to select the problematic script from the above website and cannot extract anything more down the tree: soup.find('script', {'id':'template_white-popup'})

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one. BeautifulSoup considers everything within the `<script>` tag as text. You can correct this with the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup( html, 'html')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup.find('script').text) #or .get_text() 
soup2.find("select",{'name':'choose-market'}).findAll("option")
```

**Output**

```
[<option selected="">Select Shop</option>,
 <option data-store-view="8016" value="59">  Shopnr1   </option>,
 <option data-store-view="8018" value="42"> Shopnr2     </option>,
 <option data-store-view="8013" value="27">  Shopnr3 </option>]
```

Comment: It's not a bug - this is the intended behavior. This is because script element usually don't contain HTML code.

Comment: adding .text does not change anything. Still cannot extract options. Also recreating soup  object as suggested by Andriy does not change anything. Maybe that "if" statement there brakes the html flow and beautifulsoup brakes there.

Comment: should try `.get_text()` then

Comment: Already tried .get_text() as per Andriy's answer with no luck. Python prints the script code differently when extracted with .get_text() or .text, but there is no change in result. When extracted as .get_text() there are tabs, spaces and new line characters on the screen. Without .get_text() script code is nicely formatted when printing on the console, like an html code.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat creating of the `soup` variable with the all inner of the `soup.script` via following line:

```
soup =  BeautifulSoup(soup.script.get_text())
soup.find("select",{'name':'choose-market'}).findAll("option")
```

**NOTE:** Tried to parse script with other parsers, same behaviour. Tried: `html5lib` and `lxml`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but you can try it :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen


url = 'https://www.castorama.pl/produkty/wykonczenie/drewno-i-drewnopodobne/podlogi-drewniane.html'

open = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(open,'html.parser')

script = soup.findAll('script',attrs={'id':'template_white-popup'})

for all_element in script:
    new_pne = all_element.text
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(new_pne, 'html.parser')

    select = soup2.findAll('option')

    for all_select in select:
        print all_select.text
        print all_select.get('value')
        print all_select.get('data-store-view')
        print ("----------------------------")
```

I did try and get these output :

```
      Wybierz sklep
None
None
----------------------------

                        Białystok                    
59
8016
----------------------------

                        Bielsko-Biała                    
42
8018
----------------------------

                        Bydgoszcz                    
27
8013
----------------------------

                        Bydgoszcz Szajnochy                    
87
8078
----------------------------

                        Bytom                    
43
8092
----------------------------
```